# Simple automorphism groups of field extensions of infinite transcendence degree

Tags: fields, gr.group-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $K/k$ be a field extension of infinite transcendence degree where $K$ is algebraically closed. Is it true that $\mathrm{Aut}_k(K)$ is a simple group?

The above question is motivated by work of Lascar. Lascar gives a proof of the above statement when $k=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $K=\mathbb{C}$ in his article [The group of automorphisms of the field of complex numbers leaving fixed the algebraic numbers is simple](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511629174.006).

Comment: I suppose you want $k$ to be also algebraically closed, otherwise the subgroup of elements fixing $\overline k \subseteq K$ would be a proper normal subgroup. I don't have access to Lascar's paper, but from the title I would guess he takes $k = \overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @Angelo, thank you for noticing. I meant the case where $k$ is algebraically closed as well.

Comment: A MathSciNet search gives the article *Automorphism groups of fields, and their representations* by Rovinskii, according to which Lascar actually proves the result for any extension of algebraically closed fields of uncountable transcendence degree.

Comment: I don't have access to Lascar's article neither, so I cannot check this.